# Closed form solution to the integral of a product of dirichlet distributions

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

Can we get a closed form solution to the integral of a product of dirichlet distributions? Example:

$$D(\vec{x}|\vec{\alpha}) = 
  \frac{\Gamma\left(\sum_{j=1}^d\alpha_j\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^d\Gamma(\alpha_j)} 
  \prod_{j=1}^d x_j^{\alpha_j-1}$$

$$\int\prod_{i=1}^n D(\vec{x}|\vec{\alpha}_i)$$